# Recursive summation of a sequence returning wrong result

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to retrieve the sum of the first n terms of a arithmetic sequence: 
`a(n) = n(n-1) + 4 where n(1) = 5`
So, the sum of the first 2 terms (5,9) would be 14. However, my code is not returning this. Instead I get 13. What am I missing?

```
def main():
    sequence(3,0)
    print("in main")


# 5,9,13,17,21,...
# Sum of first 2 = 14
# Sum of first 3 = 27
def sequence(n, sum):
    if (n == 1):
        return 5
    else:
        a = sequence(n-1, sum) + 4
        sum += a
        print(sum)
        return a


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    try:
        main()
    finally:
        print("done")
```

Answer (score 2):

An arithmetic sequence (or progression) with:

- A given start term: let's call it ***f**irst*
- An increment value (between any 2 consecutive terms): let's call it  ***d**iff*

is an ordered set of numbers (terms), where each term can be written as:

**`Tk = Tk - 1 + d`**, and from here:

**`Tk = T1 + (k - 1) * d`** (although I find it a bit unnatural, ***T<sub>1</sub>*** is the 1<sup>st</sup> element, so index starts from ***1***, in order that the *n*<sup>th</sup> element in the sequence has the index *n*) <sup>***(0)***</sup>

So:

> **`T1 = f`**
>
> **`T2 = f + (2 - 1) * d`** (`T1 + d`)
>
> **`T3 = f + (3 - 1) * d`** (`T2 + d`)
>
> **`T4 = f + (4 - 1) * d`**
>
> ....
>
> **`Tn - 1 = f + (n - 2) * d`**
>
> **`Tn = f + (n - 1) * d`**

Summing everything, on the ***=*** sign's **right** side:

- ***f*** appears ***n*** times
- ***d*** appears **`(n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + 2 + 1`** which is the sum of numbers til *n - 1*, and can be calculated using *Gauss*'s formula: **`(n - 1) * n // 2`**
- For this particular case, *f = 5* and *d = 4*

So, using this arithmetic sequences property, **you don't need to calculate each term, and therefore no need for recursion** altogether, instead you can (should) use a bunch simple arithmetic operations.

For more details, check [[Wikipedia]: Arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)

Back to the original problem: your function doesn't calculate the sum, but sequence's n<sup>th</sup> term (there's also a discrepancy between text and code).

The "baby steps" way of doing it would be to calculate the sequence recursively, then add the terms, but there are ways to do both in one go.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys


def arithm_seq_sum(count, first=5, diff=4):
    return count * first + ((count - 1) * count // 2) * diff


def arithm_seq_sum_rec(count, first=5, diff=4):
    if count <= 1:
        return first
    return first + (count - 1) * diff + arithm_seq_sum_rec(count - 1, first=first, diff=diff)


def arithm_seq_sum_rec0(count, term=5, diff=4):
    if count <= 1:
        return term
    return term + arithm_seq_sum_rec0(count - 1, term=term + diff, diff=diff)


def main(*argv):
    for func in (arithm_seq_sum, arithm_seq_sum_rec, arithm_seq_sum_rec0):
        print("\n{:s}:".format(func.__name__))
        for i in range(12):
            print("  {:2d} - {:d}".format(i, func(i)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Notes**:

- The sum is calculated by:

  - *arithm_seq_sum* - uses the math shortcut (I strongly recommend it)
  - *arithm_seq_sum_rec* - calculates the n<sup>th</sup> term using its math properties (from <sup>***(0)***</sup>), then uses recursion to calculate sum
  - *arithm_seq_sum_rec0* - another (uglier) recurrent implementation, which passes the (previous) term as an argument to the next call. It's the only version that requires 2 arguments

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q055479298]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
>
> arithm_seq_sum:
>    0 - 0
>    1 - 5
>    2 - 14
>    3 - 27
>    4 - 44
>    5 - 65
>    6 - 90
>    7 - 119
>    8 - 152
>    9 - 189
>   10 - 230
>   11 - 275
>
> arithm_seq_sum_rec:
>    0 - 5
>    1 - 5
>    2 - 14
>    3 - 27
>    4 - 44
>    5 - 65
>    6 - 90
>    7 - 119
>    8 - 152
>    9 - 189
>   10 - 230
>   11 - 275
>
> arithm_seq_sum_rec0:
>    0 - 5
>    1 - 5
>    2 - 14
>    3 - 27
>    4 - 44
>    5 - 65
>    6 - 90
>    7 - 119
>    8 - 152
>    9 - 189
>   10 - 230
>   11 - 275
>
> Done.
> ```

As a note, I think recursion is a nice (theoretical) thing, but due to its limitations, it should only be used in production as a last resort.

Comment: I think your _notes_ section has a typo or two in the function names.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to break it down to understand it.

```
sequence(3, 0)

# first iteration
a = sequence(2, 0) + 4
# second iteration
a = sequence(1, 0) + 4
# third iteration
return 5

# Now let's work our way backwards

a = 5 + 4 -> 9
a = 9 + 4 -> 13
```

Hence why you get 13. Is this enough of a clue to get you going in the right direction? Here is another hint, notice you are returning your sequence of numbers as opposed to their sum.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be at least a couple of confusing issues in your question.  First, you expressed the sequence formula as:

```
a(n) = n(n-1) + 4
```

but to get the results you're describing, the formula would need to be:

```
a(n) = a(n-1) + 4
```

Second, you seem to be confusing the sequence with the *summation* of the sequence.  Let's generate the sequence (recursively) and then make a running summation of the sequence (also recursively):

```
def sum_sequence(sequence):

    first, rest = sequence[0], sequence[1:]

    if rest:
        second, rest = rest[0], rest[1:]
        rest = sum_sequence([first + second] + rest)

    return [first] + rest

def generate_sequence(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 5

    return generate_sequence(n - 1) + 4

if __name__ == '__main__':

    sequence = [generate_sequence(n) for n in range(1, 11)]

    print(*sequence, sep=", ", end=", ...\n")

    sums = sum_sequence(sequence)

    print(*sums, sep=", ", end=", ...\n")
```

OUTPUT

```
% python3 test.py
5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29, 33, 37, 41, ...
5, 14, 27, 44, 65, 90, 119, 152, 189, 230, ...
%
```