# Jacobsthal number recursion formula

Tags: recursion, math

I have a very simple (and stupid :) question:

How do I get from this expression:

[image]

To this recursion formula?

[image]

I do not want any complete solution, but maybe you can help me to understand it with just a few tips.

Thx, and a nice day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very similar to [[Wikipedia]: Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), and is a typical [[Wikipedia]: Mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) example.

Starting from the assumption that the formula **is true** for (a given) ***n*** (let's call this ***P(n)***):

- **`Jn = 2 * Jn - 1 + (-1)n - 1`**

then, using the above equality and the function definition, you must prove ***P(n + 1)*** - that the formula is also true for (the consecutive) ***n + 1***. This is the one in your question:

- **`Jn + 1 = 2 * Jn + (-1)n`**

Since this is a programming site (and I'm too lazy calculating the first few values manually), here's some *Python* code that does that for us:

> ```py
> >>> def j(n):
> ...     if n <= 0:
> ...         return 0
> ...     elif n == 1:
> ...         return 1
> ...     else:
> ...         return j(n - 1) + 2 * j(n - 2)
> ... 
> >>>
> >>> for i in range(15):
> ...     print("{:2d} - {:4d}".format(i, j(i)))
> ...
>  0 -    0
>  1 -    1
>  2 -    1
>  3 -    3
>  4 -    5
>  5 -   11
>  6 -   21
>  7 -   43
>  8 -   85
>  9 -  171
> 10 -  341
> 11 -  683
> 12 - 1365
> 13 - 2731
> 14 - 5461
> ```

From the above, it's kind of noticeable by the naked eye that the formula is true. 
Now the induction mechanism should be applied: start from ***P(n)*** and using the function definition (3<sup>rd</sup> branch) get to ***P(n + 1)***. That might not be trivial, considering there's a level 2 dependency (most of the terms that will eventually reduce each other, but I didn't try it to see how "visible" that would be). 
You could check [[SO]: Recursive summation of a sequence returning wrong result (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55479298/recursive-summation-of-a-sequence-returning-wrong-result/55479893#55479893), for more details on a simpler problem.

---

**Note**:

Given the current coefficients, I must mention recursion's **characteristic equation** (check [[Wikipedia]: Constant-recursive sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-recursive_sequence)) that would give a non recurring formula for **`Jn`**:

**`Jn = Jn - 1 + 2 * Jn - 2`** translates to: **`x2 = x1 + 2 * x0`** -> **`x2 - x - 2 = 0`** (which has -1 and 2 as roots), and from here (using *Binet* (or *Moivre*) formula):

**`Jn = (2n - (-1)n) / 3`** (denominator value is: ***2 - -1***)

Let the computer do some calculations from us (check that previous implementation results match this one's):

> ```py
> >>> def j_simpl(n):
> ...     return (2 ** n - (-1) ** n) / 3
> ...
> >>>
> >>> print(all(j(i) == j_simpl(i) for i in range(20)))
> True
> ```